# How to delete old Log-analytics-workspace permanently in azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have two MS-Azure subscriptions, SUB1 and SUB2

In SUB1 I have created Log-analytics-workspace named "nonprod-app-law" and after few days I have deleted it.

In SUB2 I have created Log-analytics-workspace named "nonprod-app-law". But getting below error

ERROR:

```
0-06-28T19:29:24.0541229Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.

2020-06-28T19:29:24.0626384Z ##[error]Details:

2020-06-28T19:29:24.0627398Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Details:

2020-06-28T19:29:24.0629668Z ##[error]Conflict: The workspace name 'nonprod-app-law' is not unique

2020-06-28T19:29:24.0630757Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Conflict: The workspace name 'nonprod-app-law' is not unique
```

Answer (score 5):

If you deleted in the portal the default behavior is a soft delete. [To delete forcefully you need to run some powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/delete-workspace#permanent-workspace-delete?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321)

```
Remove-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName "resource-group-name" -Name "workspace-name" -ForceDelete
```

Comment: The correct flag is `-ForceDelete` not `-Force`!

Comment: Thanks updated. Was working at the time of original posting....wonder if updates referenced below changed it.....

Answer (score 2):

If you open the recycle bin of Log Analytics workspaces in the Azure portal, you will see a similar screen similar to the below:

[image]

To be able to add a new Log Analytics workspace with the same name to another subscription, you should first `recover` the soft-deleted one via portal or CLI. Then, you need to delete it with the `--force` flag on CLI either via [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/delete-workspace#permanent-workspace-delete) or [Az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_log_analytics_workspace_delete).

PS:

> Remove-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName
> "resource-group-name" -Name "workspace-name" -ForceDelete

Az CLI:

> az monitor log-analytics workspace delete --force true
> --resource-group MyResourceGroup --workspace-name MyWorkspace

Answer (score 0):

Force deleted using -Force tag is not working @DreadedFrost

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with PowerShell not supporting force delete, we are fixing (eta: couple of weeks). You can use REST or CLI to force delete

Comment: Does that include if using the AzureRm module?

Comment: @Oleg Ananiev  

is there any alternative of above command ?